# Why does list.dirs ignore "full.names"?

Tags: r, list, path, directory

The example:

```
> home_dir <- "C:\\Windows\\Help"

> list.dirs(home_dir, full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE)
[1] "C:\\Windows\\Help/Corporate" "C:\\Windows\\Help/Help"     
[3] "C:\\Windows\\Help/mui"       "C:\\Windows\\Help/OEM"      
[5] "C:\\Windows\\Help/Windows"  

> list.dirs(home_dir, full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)
[1] "C:\\Windows\\Help/Corporate" "C:\\Windows\\Help/Help"     
[3] "C:\\Windows\\Help/mui"       "C:\\Windows\\Help/OEM"      
[5] "C:\\Windows\\Help/Windows"
```

The question is: why does `list.dirs` return full paths in both cases and not filenames when `full.names = FALSE`? The system is Windows 8.

Comment: It's a bug fixed in 3.0.2